# From GDI to WPF: rendering

Tags: wpf, gdi

In GDI you just use System.Drawing.Graphics to manually handle the rendering.

In WPF is DrawingContext the way to go?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed override the `OnRender` method of a `UIElement` to define your own rendering instructions but note that this is not an immediate mode rendering API like Windows Forms's `OnPaint`. In fact there is no such API available in WPF.

The drawing operations of the `DrawingContext` are not used directly when the `OnRender` method is invoked. They are instead processed by the rendering thread at a later stage.

So depending on what you are trying to do, overriding the `OnRender` method may not be your best choice after all. You may want to stick to the "WPF way" of creating composite UI elements.